# Hide (or not show) the plot in mplfinance

Tags: python, plot, command-line, stock, mplfinance

I'm running mplfinance in python from the command line. I would like to hide (or not show) the plot since I save the plots as a .jpg. I later review the plots/graphs/images in an image viewer.

The problem is I have to close each image plotted for the script to proceed with defining the next graph. I don't want to see the graphs at the time of execution, and have to close each image as the script loops to create multiple graphs. In other words "fire and forget".

Is there a way to hide (or not show) the plot in mplfinance

I appreciate any help.

Thanks,

Manny

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This notebook demonstrates how you can save the plot to a file directly from `mplfinance`](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/blob/master/examples/savefig.ipynb) and the plot will be "hidden", that is, not displayed on the screen (*only saved to the file*).

---

There is also a somewhat related kwarg, but I don't think it's what you want based on what you described; just so you are aware in case you find use for it in the future:

If you  pass in `block=False` then the plot will still be displayed on screen, but your script will move on to the next plot without "blocking" and waiting for you to close the first plot.  This is useful if you want to see 2 or more plots on the screen at a time.  One thing to note though ... for the last plot in the script you may want to let `block` default to `True`, or in some other way cause the script to stop and wait for input before exiting, because when the script exits then all open plots will close automatically as their objects go out of scope.

HTH.  All the best.  --Daniel

Comment: Hello Daniel:

It seems it comes down to including the "savefig = ThisChart" argument in "mpf.plot("  doesn't produce (hides) a visible the plot: is that about right? 

Thanks for the help.

Manny

Comment: Yes, Manny, that's correct, `savefig=filename` will NOT display the plot on-screen, BUT WILL SAVE the plot to a file which you can view later with any image viewer.  If the filename includes a commonly known extension (such as ".png" or ".jpg") then `savefig` will save an image file of the type implied by the extension.